# how to get values from jsp in ${clue.text}

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I define a class of Clue :

```
Class Clue{
  ...
  String text;
  ..
  getter/setter method
}
```

I want to get ${clue.text} from jsp to use in the scope "<%...%>" to just show subSequence(0, 10),like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${clues}" var = "clue">
    <tr>
    <td>${clue.weibo.user.name}</td>
    <td>
    <%
    String str = ${clue.weibo.text};
    %>
    <%=str.subSequence(0, 10) %>
    </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

How can I do?

Comment: Your code above lacks a problem statement I fear - if you add your desired result we could help better.

Comment: Also it can be old Servlet specification into web.xml and no jsp resolver.

Comment: @Smutje I just want to make value in ${} to <% ... %>

Comment: That's not a problem statement - a problem statement would be something like "I want to use the value of clue.weibo.text in a method parameter" or "I want to use the value of clue.weibo.text to be printed out".

Comment: And `<%=clue.weibo.text.subSequence(0, 10) %>` does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access A JSTL variable in a scriplet:

```
<%
String str = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("clue.weibo.text", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
%>
```

However, a better way is to use JSTL functions to manipulate the string.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<c:forEach items="${clues}" var = "clue">
    <tr>
    <td>${clue.weibo.user.name}</td>
    <td>
    ${fn:substring(clue.weibo.text, 0, 10)}
    </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```